# Sudden Approximation for Beta Decay of Tritium Atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I am working out this problem right now, and I'm confused by the answers I'm getting.
Problem:
A tritium nucleus (Z = 1) in a tritium atom undergoes beta decay, i.e., a neutron in the nucleus emits an electron and transforms into a proton (Z = 2). Assuming that the emitted electron acquires so much energy that becomes unbound and flies away almost instantly without interacting with the orbiting electron,

(i) Compute the probability that the bound electron will be in a state with principal quantum number n in the Helium ion. Assume that initially the bound electron was in the ground state of the tritium atom.

Attempt:

The new wavefunctions differ by Z=2, and we want to calculate transition probability between the old ground state and the new wavefunctions, so we take the inner product between them. Looking at the hydrogen wave function, by orthogonality of the spherical harmonics the inner product will vanish if the l's aren't equal, so l'=l=0, which simplifies our inner product, which is now an integral over r. My final expression for the transition probablity is:

(Integrate[(8*Sqrt[2]/a^3)*1^(-5/2)*LaguerreL[1 - 1, 1, 2*2*r/(1*a)]*
    LaguerreL[0, 1, 2*r/(a)]*Exp[-r/a - 4*r/(1*a)]*r^2, {r, 0, 
    Infinity}])^2

or 128*(Integrate[
    n^(-5/2)*LaguerreL[n - 1, 1, 4*r/n]*Exp[-r - 4*r/(n)]*r^2, {r, 0, 
     Infinity}])^2

So I get an expression of 512/15625 for the probability it is in the new ground state. This is really low. I am supposed to calculate the infinite sum of these probabilities as well, with mathematica, but it can't figure it out. So either I'm doing something wrong in my thought process, or there is a way of writing of the laguerre polynomial that simplifies our problem considerably.

Comment: As you suggested, writing out the definition of the associated (!) Laguerre polynomial LaguerreL[n-1, 1, x] should simplify your expression.

Comment: Mmm I just rewrote the expression to n/32*(Integrate[
    LaguerreL[n - 1, 1, r]*Exp[-r*(n/4 + 1)]*r^2, {r, 0, Infinity}])^2, and I'm going to expand it

Comment: @Neuneck what simplification should I be looking for? There's a few definitions of the associated Laguerre polynomial that I could use. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Explicit_examples_and_properties_of_the_associated_Laguerre_polynomials

Comment: I think the Rodrigues formula is useful.

Comment: @Neuneck so I think I was able to take your hint and get a sum. But the sum is ~0.036, so it's not unitary. Physically, do you know why that is?

P(0->n)=$512 (-2 + n)^2 n^{-1 + 2 n} (4 + n)^{-4 - 2 n}$

Comment: Perhaps I can divide P(0-->0') by the sum, to normalize it? Or perhaps it's not supposed to be unitary, but then I wouldn't know what other states it could be in..